# Combining two numpy arrays to form an array with the largest value from each array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, max

I want to combine two numpy arrays to produce an array with the largest values from each array.

```
import numpy as np

a  = np.array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.5],
               [ 0.1,  0.5,  0.5],
               [ 0.1,  0.,  0.]])

b  = np.array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.0],
               [ 0.5,  0.1,  0.5],
               [ 0.5,  0.1,  0.]])
```

I would like to produce

```
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.5],
       [ 0.5,  0.5,  0.5],
       [ 0.5,  0.1,  0.]])
```

I know you can do

```
a += b
```

which results in

```
array([[ 0. ,  0. ,  0.5],
       [ 0.6,  0.6,  1. ],
       [ 0.6,  0.1,  0. ]])
```

This is clearly not what I'm after. It seems like such an easy problem and I assume it most probably is.

Answer (score 10):

You can use [`np.maximum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.maximum.html) to compute the element-wise maximum of the two arrays:

```
>>> np.maximum(a, b)
array([[ 0. ,  0. ,  0.5],
       [ 0.5,  0.5,  0.5],
       [ 0.5,  0.1,  0. ]])
```

This works with any two arrays, as long as they're the same shape or one can be [broadcast](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to the shape of the other.

To modify the array `a` in-place, you can redirect the output of `np.maximum` back to `a`:

```
np.maximum(a, b, out=a)
```

There is also [`np.minimum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.minimum.html) for calculating the element-wise minimum of two arrays.

Answer (score 6):

You are looking for the element-wise maximum.

**Example:**

```
>>> np.maximum([2, 3, 4], [1, 5, 2])
array([2, 5, 4])
```

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.maximum.html

Answer (score 3):

```
inds =  b > a
a[inds] = b[inds]
```

This modifies the original array `a` which is what `+=` is doing in your example which may or may not be what you want.